# Is it possible to populate treeview from an array?

Tags: c#, wpf

Or would this be a bad practice? In one of my last questions I was told it is not good practice to reference/access UIElements from the code behind.
 So is there a better solution to send arrays to a treeview?
 I dont even know if an array is OK to use here, maybe a stringbuilder.
 I just know that this worked in my winform so I kinda kept it.
 ...Anyway, I have created a checklist application that sends some arrays to a listbox.

This is my xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstToDo" Margin="188,10,10,38" FontSize="14" SelectionMode="Extended" UseLayoutRounding="False" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}">
                        <CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                        </CheckBox.LayoutTransform>
                    </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I have about 50 different arrays that I might send to that listbox based on which button the user the users presses. 
This is a sample of one of my arrays:

```
string[] Install_MySQL = {
                                "1. If you don’t have a SQL engine, install MySQL. ",
                                "a. MySQL Server 5.0",
                                "i. Typical",
                                "ii.    Note: Select Custom if you want to install MySQL to a location other than the default, C:\\Program Files.",
                                "b. MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard",
                                "i. Select the Detailed Configuration radio button and click Next ",
                                "ii.    select “Server Machine” if you expect to run other applications on this server ",
                                "iii.   Select “Transactional Database Only”",
                                "iv.    select the location for your Tablespace ",
                                "v. To allow for enough connections, select the OLTP option ",
                                "vi.    Unless you have a specific reason for changing it, leave the default value of Port 3306.", 
                                "vii.   Standard Character Set",
                                "viii.  accept the “Install As Windows Service” and “Launch the MySQL Server Automatically” ",
                                "ix.    user: root   pass: Synergy1 – enable remote access",
                                "x. execute – cross fingers ",
                                "c. Install MySQL Administration Tools for MySQL 5.0",
                                "i. mysql-gui-tools-com-5.0-r12-win32.msi",
                                "ii.    select complete Install",
                                "2. More stuff",
                                "a. some more stuff",
                                "b. even more stuff",
                            };
```

This is how I send that array to the listbox:

```
private void InstallMySQLTool()
    {
        foreach (string s in Install_MySQL)
        {
            lstToDo.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

I definitely believe a treeview would be a better solution for a checklist because I could collapse the each sublist right?
Is there a way I could build these list in xaml itself and still populate it based on different buttons?

Comment: I was going to write an answer with a mini-version of what you are trying to do, but I think there is a lot of value in sending you this [`link`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) instead. The MVVM pattern is ideal for this type of situation and it would help you to get a bit of an understanding as to how WPF (and the WPF TreeView, specifically) influences you to follow it. Please take a look first, and if it is confusing, I'm happy to offer some help.

Comment: Thanks, I think this tutorial will be exactly what I was looking for.